# Best way to store SVGs?

Tags: fieldtype

What are some ways to store full SVGs to later embed onto a page?
I'm thinking of setting a multiline plain text field to store the raw SVG.

Maybe save the file and embed it onto the page via javascript or php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However you'd like. Yes, you could store them in a multiline plain text field, but why not use them as SVG files? Unless you are using channel entries to generate CSS content (which would be a very weird thing to do, unless you're specifically making a site that allows people to play with the SVG format), SVG files can be loaded by most modern browsers just fine. And the only other place to use them is in your stylesheets.

I gather you just want a way to store the plaintext of an SVG string. So you already have your answer.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML

References in case you needed them.